# Using drush to assigne user roles

Tags: php, drupal-7, drush

I am trying to use drush to assign the user role "content author" to a user on a drupal7 site, however I get this error.

```
drush @mysite.com urol 'content author' --uid=15
Could not find a uid for the search term 'author'!                   [error]
There is no role named: content                                      [error]
```

I have tried assigning 'administrator' role to this user with the same drush command and it works fine, however, any other roles that its name contains two words don't work. Looking at the list of roles and I can see;

```
+-----+--------------------+--------+
| rid | name               | weight |
+-----+--------------------+--------+
|   3 | administrator      |      2 |
|   1 | anonymous user     |      0 |
|   2 | authenticated user |      1 |
|   4 | content author     |      3 |
|   5 | forum moderator    |      4 |
+-----+--------------------+--------+
```

I understand that the machine name should be used when using the drush command to assign roles, but referring to the records of `role` table there isn't any other name given to the roles. I have also tried 'content_author', 'content-author' but no luck. Can someone please help me get this right.  Thanks!

Comment: What version of Drush are you using? `drush --version`

Comment: Have you tried `content_author` with an underscore, the machine name?

Comment: Also try double quotes around the role. `drush @mysite.com urol "content author" --uid=15`

Comment: I am using `Drush Version:  6.2.0 `. As mentioned in the description of the issue I have tried `content_author`, `content-author`, `contentAuthor`, `contentauthor` non of them works. I have also tried all of those options with the double quotes, but no luck.

Comment: Update to Drush 8 and retry, see https://docs.drush.org/en/8.x/install/#drupal-compatibility.

Comment: unfortunately, I am not able to change the drush version. ;-(

Comment: Uh. And other roles with spaces? Do they work?

Comment: That is right, any role name with space doesn't work

Comment: Did you try to escape space into name ? like `drush @mysite.com urol 'content\ author' --uid=15` ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried all of that. I believe the issue is in drush and it can't handle user roles with space.